# Multiple linecharts with different Y scales with shareable X Axis using d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot, linechart

Im working on this project where I have a big amount of data. It's segmented by categories `Soybean, MA20,  MA50, MA100, BBW_2` and `date`.
What I've done so far was to use a code where you can filter and zoom in the data. The result is

- Selecting Soybean:[image]
- Selecting MA50: [image]
- Selecting BBW_2 !HERE IS THE PROBLEM! :[image]
  The problem is when BBW_2 is selected. You can see an orange line touching the X axis. This is BBW_2. It has it's Y' axis max value of 2, which is infinitely smaller than 1200, so the scale doesn't work as expected. This doesn't occur with the other categories because they have similar Y' axis values.

**What Do I Want to Achieve?**

I want to plot all the categories that the user selects appending the selected categories`generated linechart to the same X axis but with different Y scales. One example of what it would look like is this one: [image].

**What I've tried:**

- Change the Y scale by changing it when the user selects BBW_2.
- Plot in different SVG`s. This doesnt work great because it loses the zooming effect.

**The code:**
https://jsfiddle.net/ldepaula/3q1k9hyj/1/